# Access specified product on custom URL

Tags: magento-1.9, product, layout, controllers

Greetings StackExchange.

I' have a task where I cannot google anything on the subject.

I want to create a copy of the standard Magento product view but it should be accessible on a custom URL.

I have created a small module that loads up a empty template page on the URL `myshop.test/productoftheday`.

Is there a way i can use the following to my benefit?

1. I have succeeded to reuse the layout and template files of `catalog_product_view`.
2. In my `php-error.log` the following is showing:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() in
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Review/Block/Product/View/List.php:40"

3. Is there anything in the controller `app/core/mage/catalog/controllers/productcontroller` I can use to load the view correct regarding list item 2?

Comment: You meant to say you want load specific product on custom page?

Comment: @RaviSoni Yes exactly. With the same functionality as the product view with minor layout changes :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Block file, you can create below function

```
public function getProdcut() {
    $productId = 11; //your specific prodcut ID
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    return $product;
}
```

Now in your new layout PHTML file, you should get your product like below

```
<?php $product = $this->getProdcut() ?>
```

Here it's your specific product.

**$product**

Comment: I think we misunderstand eachother :) 

I have the standard productpage eg. https://www.helsebixen.dk/shop/magnesium-citrat-400-10176p.html 

Then i want the excact same layout on a custom url  eg https://www.helsebixen.dk/shop/productoftheday